# Unit test method that uses -[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uiscrollview

In my custom subclass of `UIScrollView`, how can I unit test a method called `-zoomToPoint:scale:animated:`?

I would like to test that this method correctly modifies the `contentOffset` and `zoomScale` of `MyScrollView`. I would like the implementation of this method to use `-[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:]` because that seems to be the normal way of focusing a region in a `UIScrollView`.

<strike>I am having trouble because even when I pass `NO` as the `animated` parameter of `-zoomToRect:animated:` it still seems to animate. I would expect `UIScrollView` to immediately set the `contentOffset` and `zoomScale` but this does not seem to be the case.</strike>

Comment: When I said "even when I pass NO as the `animated` parameter of `-zoomToRect:animated:` it still seems to animate", I believe this is because I was incorrectly calling the method. From my experimentation, it seems to have undefined results when the zoom rect is larger than the content size. When I pass in a valid zoom rect, it seems to respect the `animated` parameter. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23902659/1529675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [FBSnapshotTestcase](https://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case)

A "snapshot test case" takes a configured UIView or CALayer and uses the renderInContext: method to get an image snapshot of its contents. It compares this snapshot to a "reference image" stored in your source code repository and fails the test if the two images don't match.

It will help you test the exact zoomScale that you want

Comment: Thanks for the tip @KingBabar I might use that later on. However, I want to avoid hitting the filesystem so we can conveniently run many tests, and this particular method has so many edge cases I would like to test that a snapshot of a single case wouldn't be enough to make me feel confident that it works in every case.

Comment: Update: Yeah I found this to be the most reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a table of example content sizes, bounds sizes, zoom scales, min zoom scales, max zoom scales, destination zoom points, destination zoom scales, expected content offsets, and expected zoom scales. In other words the table summarized the expected outputs given a bunch of possible inputs, with an effort to exercise every edge case I could think of.

I wrote test cases to verify each combination of values in this table. Each test would set up a scroll view with the given parameters, call `-zoomToPoint:scale:animated:` with an `animated` parameter of `NO`, then verify the `contentOffset` and `zoomScale`. I passed `NO` to the `animate` parameter in all of the cases, so I am making the assumption that it gives the same end result when animated. If necessary in the future, I may add tests that pass `YES` to the `animated` parameter and verify the `contentOffset` and `zoomScale` after letting several run loops pass, but that would be a whole other thing to figure out and I don't want to do that right now.

As a result, my resulting `-zoomToPoint:scale:animated:` method behavior looks awesome in every edge case I have been able to test.