# -[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:] weird behavior when contentSize < bounds.size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Can anyone precisely describe the behavior of `-[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:]` ? This method really seems to do some complicated stuff, but Apple's documentation of it is very sparse.

I am getting unpredictable behavior of this method when the content size is smaller than the size of the scroll view in width and/or height. In some cases, this method causes the scroll view to have a negative content offset when it should be 0. Passing slightly different rects, it leaves the content offset at 0 like I would expect.

To demonstrate this weird behavior, I set up an example project with a **scroll view of size (200, 200)** containing a **content view of size (100, 100)**. I would expect that **zooming to rect ((0, 0), (200, 200))** of the content view should leave the content in the top left (i.e. **nothing should happen**). However, it actually causes the content to scroll to the bottom right of the scroll view's bounds (content offset (-100, -100)). Why does this happen?

[image: Screen Recording]

Here is the code in my example project:

```
@implementation RootViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .5;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4;

    self.contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)]];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.contentView;
}

- (void)handleTap {
    [self.scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200) animated:YES]; // Try changing to 199, 199 to get completely different behavior
}

@end
```

Thanks for any insights! Right now I am guessing `UIScrollView` just isn't designed to display content smaller than its own size. My use case is that I may have a content view that is wider than the scroll view but shorter in height, and I need to be able to scroll to either the right or left end of this content view programmatically.

Comment: What sense could it make to have a content size smaller than the bounds? Set the unused dimension to match the bounds and move on.

Comment: Oh, and iOS will let you hang yourself by scrolling to places the user cannot scroll to. Solution: don't do that.

Comment: @jaggedcow Yes I am setting the `contentSize`. And even in that degenerate case I would it to put the content in the top left.

Comment: For your use case, why are you using zoomToRect: as opposed to scrollToRect: or just setting the contentOffset?

Comment: @matt I want to be able to display a scrollable view that may be very small (its size depends on user input) in either dimension. So lets say I am displaying a panorama photo that is 1000x100pts. I could pad the photo view with extra space on the top and bottom but I don't want to go down that road because then the user would be able to zoom into the black space above and below the photo.

Comment: @jaggedcow I am implementing a method called `-zoomToPoint:withScale:animated:`. This will be used by a double tap to zoom feature and also for programmatically centering points of interest in the content view. So I need to support zooming too. That said, if I can't get `-zoomToRect:animated:` to work the way I want then I might try directly setting the `contentOffset` and `zoomScale` like you suggest. I just wasn't sure if that is good practice.

Comment: It might help you to look at my example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch07p376zoomCentered/ch20p680zoomCentered Shows you how to allow zooming while keeping the zoomable view centered.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I didn't notice those methods `-setContentOffset:animated:` and `-setZoomScale:animated:` when I was reading the docs. I think I might got with those. Also, didn't know `self->_iVar` would work for Objective C objects ;)

Comment: So I tried using `-setContentOffset:animated:` together with `-setZoomScale:animated:` and they gave the correct end result, but the animation looked very unnatural and jerky... probably because the interpolation functions for the two animations didn't line up in a natural way. Going with `-zoomToRect:animated:` and [this hacky solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23901362/1529675) I shared below gave the correct result.

Comment: This behaviour (bug?) is killing me, right now.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov My `-setContentOffset:` solution below worked out for me. Alternatively, another hypothesis I had is that setting the `contentInset` of the scroll view such that the content size plus the inset size is greater than or equal to the scroll view size might solve the issue... I haven't tested it, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: @tboyce12 It worked for me as well, thanks a lot. However, I had to spend the time trying to fix it properly before applying a hack, and that was pure madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless someone has a better answer, I'm going to conclude that calling `-zoomToRect:animated:` has undefined results when the resulting `contentSize` is smaller than the `bounds` size in either dimension. In other words, the content should be larger than the scroll view if you want to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is wondering, this is what I may do in this case. I'm going to see if it plays well with the unit tests for the scroll view subclass I'm implementing in my real life project. However, this doesn't answer the original question of "Can anyone precisely describe the behavior of `-[UIScrollView zoomToRect:animated:]` ?" so I'm still hoping for more answers.

Well, here goes (I hate hackery like this):

```
@implementation TBScrollView // Subclass of UIScrollView

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    contentOffset.x = MAX(contentOffset.x, 0);
    contentOffset.y = MAX(contentOffset.y, 0);
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
}

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated {
    contentOffset.x = MAX(contentOffset.x, 0);
    contentOffset.y = MAX(contentOffset.y, 0);
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:animated];
}

@end
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately this has the unfortunate side effect that you can no longer bounce scrolling on the left side for larger images where that should be allowed (requires negative content offset). I'm going to look for another solution to my use case.

**EDIT 2:** I got around the above-mentioned side effect by only disabling negative content offsets while a `-zoomToRect:animated:` animation is taking place. I declared a `BOOL` property, set it to `YES` before calling `-zoomToRect:animated:`, and set it back to `NO` afterwards if `animated` was `NO`. Otherwise, I set the property to `NO` during `-scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` (called if `-zoomToRect:animated:` didn't cause any change in scale) and `-scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:` (called if `-zoomToRect:animated:` did cause a change in scale). This is kind of a hacky solution and I worry that it may break with a future iOS release, but at least I have it all supported by unit tests :)

Comment: You don't need two methods; the first calls the second.

Comment: From my testing, the first does not call the second

Comment: Yup, you're right, I had it backwards: the second calls the first.